# Sparse SVD weird behavior

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction, svd, sparse

I'm finding the SVD for this matrix (in **Python**), and truncating it to the 4 first components:

[image]

When using: `U, Sigma, V = np.linalg.svd(m.todense(), full_matrices=True);         reducedMatrix2 = np.array(m.todense() @ V.T[:, :k])`

I get this output:

```
 [[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.17463641e-16  -8.55186110e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.17463641e-17  -8.55186110e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.17463641e-16  -8.55186110e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00  -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00  -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00  -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -8.55186110e-01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```

I find it more or less predictable. Note that the users and files were coded by alphabetic order - so the cells moved, but it can be understood what should be where.

But when I use the sparse implementation:

```
U, Sigma, Vt = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(m, k, which='LM'); reducedMatrix2 = m @ Vt.T[:, :k]
```

I get this weird out put:

```
[[ 0.22454072  0.2015693   0.20726921  0.77287389]
 [ 0.47108319  0.13437953 -0.70079178  0.01602902]
 [ 0.47108319  0.13437953 -0.70079178  0.01602902]
 [ 0.47108319  0.13437953 -0.70079178  0.01602902]
 [ 0.22454072  0.2015693   0.20726921  0.77287389]
 [ 0.22454072  0.2015693   0.20726921  0.77287389]
 [ 0.46842272  0.47032837  0.3967165  -0.36514475]
 [ 0.46842272  0.47032837  0.3967165  -0.36514475]
 [ 0.46842272  0.47032837  0.3967165  -0.36514475]
 [-0.48947475  0.67189766 -0.19972396  0.02053336]
 [-0.48947475  0.67189766 -0.19972396  0.02053336]
 [-0.48947475  0.67189766 -0.19972396  0.02053336]]
```

Where did all the zeros go? 
The numbers in the output matrix changed slightly when I change the v0 parameter of the sparse implementation.

I realize that my input is not representing the actual use case for sparse SVD, but I'm trying to understand this behavior in general.